# How can I list all tables without a primary key?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, information-schema

I've seen a ton of queries to list primary and foreign keys but how can I query for tables *missing* a primary key?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To list all tables without a primary key, you can use this:

```
select tbl.table_schema, 
       tbl.table_name
from information_schema.tables tbl
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  and table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  and not exists (select 1 
                  from information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
                  where kcu.table_name = tbl.table_name 
                    and kcu.table_schema = tbl.table_schema)
```

It's not clear to me if you want to find tables that are not referencing any other tables or tables that are not referenced by other tables. But both things can be obtained by querying `information_schema.referential_constraints` in a similar way as the above query.

Answer (score 6):

Another one query to get all tables without primary keys:

```
SELECT table_schema || '.' || table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE
    (table_catalog, table_schema, table_name) NOT IN (
        SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
        FROM information_schema.table_constraints
        WHERE constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY') AND
    table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog', 'pgq', 'londiste');
```

Unfortunately PostgreSQL has no idea what tables are supposed to have FKs. So it is manual work, you will need to look over all the tables and find such tables by yourself.

Comment: The accepted answer does not work, this one does!

Comment: This version appears to find views, not just tables

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with @a_horse_with_no_name's answer, which missed tables for me. grayhemp's returned views and gave me completely wrong results in our production environment for some reason.

I wrote this query from scratch, querying the Postgres-specific tables like `pg_class`. In general I find querying these tables is faster as well (I assume because the `information_schema` tables are actually massive views), which is nice if you're running this kind of query in a test.

```sql
SELECT pgc.relname 
FROM pg_class pgc
JOIN pg_namespace pgns ON pgns.oid = pgc.relnamespace
WHERE pgns.nspname = 'public'
AND pgc.relkind = 'r'
AND pgc.oid NOT IN

    (SELECT pgc.oid
    FROM pg_class pgc
    JOIN pg_index pgi ON pgi.indrelid = pgc.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace pgns ON pgns.oid = pgc.relnamespace

    WHERE pgi.indisprimary = true
    AND pgc.relkind = 'r'
    AND pgns.nspname = 'public'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query for FKs.

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name NOT IN (
   SELECT distinct table_name
        FROM information_schema.table_constraints
        WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' and table_schema ='xxxxx') AND
    table_schema ='xxxxx'
```